# React Bootstrap Carousel Interval only advances one slide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

I am new to react and have been trying to figure out why my `React Bootstrap Carousel` works just fine when I use the navigation arrows, but when I add the interval property, the carousel will only advance one slide and then it never calls the `onSelect` method again.

Here is the full html with the interval set.  It stops on slide two but you can use the navigation forward and backward and it works.  Also, setting the interval to `null` allows full forward and backward navigation through the slides.

The `React Controlled Carousel` demo was the basis for this code and I did not see any additional functions required for adding auto slide interval functionality.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>React Bootstrap Carousel Demo</title>
<!-- styles -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
 .carousel
 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  height: 500px;
  width: 900px !important;
 }
 
 .carousel-control
 {
  /* opacity: 0 !important; */
  width: 5% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  margin-bottom: 30px !important;
 }
 
 .carousel-control:focus, .carousel-control:hover 
 {
     color: #2D2D2D !important;
 }
</style>
<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.31.5/react-bootstrap.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.5.10/prop-types.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
<div id="application"></div>

<script>
"use strict";
  
class FrontPageCarousel extends React.Component 
{
 static get propTypes() {
  return {
   slides: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };
 }

 static get defaultProps() {
  return {
   slides: [
    {key: 0, index: 0, direction: '', imgSrc: 'img/carousel.png', capTitle: 'Slide One', capDesc: 'Slide One Description', alt: '900 x 500 Image', active: false },
    {key: 1, index: 1, direction: '', imgSrc: 'img/carousel.png', capTitle: 'Slide Two', capDesc: 'Slide Two Description', alt: '900 x 500 Image', active: false },
    {key: 2, index: 2, direction: '', imgSrc: 'img/carousel.png', capTitle: 'Slide Three', capDesc: 'Slide Three Description', alt: '900 x 500 Image', active: false }
   ]
  };
 }
 
 constructor(props,context) 
 {  
   super(props);
   this.state={
    index: null,
    direction: null
   };

   this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
 }
 
 handleSelect(selectedIndex, event)
 {  
  this.setState({
   index: selectedIndex,
   direction: event.direction
  });
 }

 render() 
 {
  var _this = this;
  
  var slides = this.props.slides.map(function(s, index) 
  {
   if(index === _this.state.index)
   {
    s.active = true;
    return React.createElement(ImageSlide, s);
   }
   else
   {
    s.active = false; 
    return React.createElement(ImageSlide, s);
   }
  });
  
  return (
   React.createElement(
    ReactBootstrap.Carousel,
    { 
     activeIndex: this.state.index, 
     defaultActiveIndex: 0,
     direction: this.state.direction, 
     onSelect: this.handleSelect,
     interval: 1000
    },
    slides
   )
  )
 }
};

/* carousel item */
class ImageSlide extends React.Component
{
 static get propTypes() {
  return {
   active: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
   index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
   direction: PropTypes.string,
   alt: PropTypes.string,
   imgSrc: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   capTitle: PropTypes.string,
   capDesc: PropTypes.string
  };
 }

 constructor(props)
 {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    active: this.props.active,
    index: null,
    direction: null
  };
 }

 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)
 {
  this.setState({
   active: nextProps.active, 
   index: nextProps.index, 
   direction: nextProps.direction
  });
  }
 
 render () 
 {
  return (
   React.createElement(
    ReactBootstrap.Carousel.Item,
    {
     active: this.state.active, 
     index: this.state.index,
     direction: this.state.direction
    },
    React.createElement(
     'img',
     {
      alt: this.props.alt, 
      src: this.props.imgSrc 
     },
     null
    ),
    React.createElement(
     ReactBootstrap.Carousel.Caption,
     null,
     React.createElement(
      "h3",
      null,
      this.props.capTitle
     ),
     React.createElement(
      "p",
      null,
      this.props.capDesc
     )
    )
   )
  )
 }
}

const fpCarousel = React.createElement(FrontPageCarousel, null);

ReactDOM.render(
 fpCarousel,
 document.getElementById("application")
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```